# P4Connection class is unavailable in P4api.net

Tags: perforce, p4.net, p4api.net

I am trying to use P4Connection class and the problem is that I could not find that class in the p4api.net library that I have downloaded recently.

Currently I am working with the use of Repository class which is not going well without the use of P4Connection class. And so, I need someone to assist me to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing the use of P4API.NET and P4.NET. Repository is part of P4API.NET, but P4Connection is part of P4.NET.

Comment: Thanks. I have confused with both. But what are their purpose? Where they developed for different motives? How they are different and where are they applicable?

Comment: P4.NET is older than P4API.NET, and isn't an official Perforce product. P4API.NET is the official C# interface provided by Perforce. You should be able to do pretty much all the same things with either, so I would just stick to whichever one you find easiest to use.